# Parse.User.current() returns null after successful login

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to using Parse and the Back4App platform. I am using the `Parse JavaScript API` in my `React` app.

The simple method of logging in `Parse.User.logIn(username, password);` works as expected;

Example:

```
Parse.User.logIn(username, password).then(function success(usr) {
  console.log(Parse.User.current());
});
```

Successfully logs to console:

```
ParseUser {_objCount: 0, className: "_User", id: "iiwzrQOyCM"}
```

However whenever I attempt to grab `Parse.User.current()` anywhere else in the app, after logging in, it returns `null`.

I watched a tutorial which showed a Parse key/value being set in Local Storage however my code, whilst virtually identical, does not do this. I have enabled cookies to make sure it wasn't that.

What am I overlooking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe problem is related to async storage system.

Can you try to access to current user with following way

```
Parse.User.currentAsync().then(function(user) {
    console.log(user)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems the issue was more fundamental. I was importing `const Parse = require("parse/node");` when I should have been importing `const Parse = require("parse");`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was a fundamental flaw in my initial Parse import statement.

I was using `const Parse = require("parse/node");` but I should have been using `const Parse = require("parse");`